# pgAdmin toolbar shows weird characters (bad i18n)

Tags: pgadmin, pgadmin-4

So I installed PGAdmin 4 v2 and the toolbar and many other things seem to have the wrong characters (see image below). My machine is running windows 10. I tried swapping the language to chinese and back to english but no luck. Any Ideas on how to solve?

(pgAdmin details below)
Version 2.0
Python Version2.7.13 (v2.7.13:a06454b1afa1, Dec 17 2016, 20:42:59) [MSC v.1500 32 bit (Intel)]
Flask Version0.12.2

[image]

Comment: Can you try with latest version of pgAdmin4 v2.1? Download: https://www.postgresql.org/ftp/pgadmin/pgadmin4/v2.1/windows/